# Invalid converting function pointer to member function

Tags: c++, pointers

my problem is invalid converting function pointer to member function.
Everything is fine when coap_handler member function is static.
CoapClient's instance can't be static and global. I want to remove static from coap_handler(). How to make it? Thanks

```
class CoapClient{
...
void connect(){    
mg_connect(&mgr, address.c_str(), coap_handler);
}

static  void coap_handler(struct mg_connection *nc, int ev, void *p) {
...

}
};
```

////// Signature `mg_connect function`

```
struct mg_connection *mg_connect(struct mg_mgr *mgr, const char *address,
                                 mg_event_handler_t callback);
```

////// Signature of `mg_event_handler_t`

Callback function (event handler) prototype. Must be defined by the user.
  Mongoose calls the event handler, passing the events defined below.

```
typedef void (*mg_event_handler_t)(struct mg_connection *, int ev, void *);
```

Comment: You cannot? Member function pointers need to have an instance to call them actully.

Comment: The connect method is invoked in a constructor of CoapClient class.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem actually.

Comment: Nope! Self contained in your question please ()and obey the ***minimal** that time.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `mg_mgr_init` and its `user_data` parameter?

Comment: Is `mgr` in `connect()` a member of `CoapClient` (can't tell if member or not)

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a member-function-pointer to a regular function pointer, you'll need a "trampoline".

Assuming that each `CoapClient` owns it's own `mg_mgr`, you can provide it with a pointer to the class instance during construction:

```
struct CoapClient {
    mg_mgr mgr_;  // _ suffix to annotate member variable
    std::string address_;

    CoapClient() {
        mg_mgr_init(&mgr_, self);  // `self` is mg_mgr's userData.
    }

    // We need a regular/static function to pass to the handler,
    // this is the trampoline:
    static connect_handler(mg_connection* conn, int ev, void *userData) {
        auto instance = static_cast<CoapClient>(userData);
        userData->onConnect(conn, ev);
    }

    void onConnect(mg_connection* conn, int ev);

    void connect() {
        mg_connect(&mgr_, address_.c_str(), connect_handler);
    }
}
```

Or we could use a lambda and boil it down to:

```
struct CoapClient {
    mg_mgr mgr_;  // _ suffix to annotate member variable
    std::string address_;

    CoapClient() {
        mg_mgr_init(&mgr_, self);  // `self` is mg_mgr's userData.
    }

    void onConnect(mg_connection* conn, int ev);

    void connect() {
        mg_connect(&mgr_, address_.c_str(), [](mg_connection* conn, int ev, void *ud) {
            static_cast<CoapClient*>(ud)->onConnect(conn, ev);
        });
    }
}
```